# Parse for Android : ParseUser.logOut() doesn't log user out

Tags: android, parse-platform, logout

I've been playing around with Parse on Android for a few days, I have a problem with ParseUser.logOut() => it actually doesn't log the current user out.

Here's what I do :

```
private void onClickOnDisconnect() {
    ParseUser.logOut();
    currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser(); // should be null but isn't...
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disconnected...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

After the call to `ParseUser.logOut()`, `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` should return null (says the documentation). Still it returns the previously logged in user.
Even though I restart the app the user is still considered as connected.

I use parse framework v1.3.8 (downloaded a 3 days ago). I don't use Facebook SDK, as I've seen a few questions for that specific case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure it is null ?

Comment: see https://www.parse.com/questions/issues-with-parseuserlogout-on-android

Comment: Is your Toast showing?

Comment: @njzk2 Yes it is null. I saw this post, it's related to Facebook, and I had tried the solution anyway but it didn't work.

Comment: @Binghammer Yes, it is showing and the menu is properly beeing invalidated

Comment: Finally I got it to work. Whatever I tried, logOut() never worked => getCurrentUseer() kept returning the same user and it was no anonymous user. Even when I removed the app and reinstalled it, it kept returning the named user. When it worked I did the following : I deleted the user on Parse data browser then removed the app. I'm not really sure what the cause was, maybe when I had created the user "Automatic logon" was activated and it somehow stuck to the user entity... Anyway now it works. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere in your app, probably the appDelegate you most likely send this message to the PFUserClass

```
[PFUser enableAutomaticUser];
```

in this case the

```
[PFUser currentUser];
```

will never return nil;

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue while incorporating logout functionality with facebook login. The error turned out to quite simple and a basic mistake on my part. I had written the following piece of code in my Application class

ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();

This creates the user every time you run your application even if you have logged out the last time around. Removing this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments above, I got it to work by :

1. uninstalling the app
2. deleting the user on the Parse dashboard
3. reinstalling the app and signing up again

Then the signout/signin mechanism worked miraculously :|

The only reason I can imagine is that I had previously signed up with this user having  *Automatic user creation* enabled, and it somehow stuck to the user entity in Parse.

Answer (score 1):

Experiencing same bug. Now instead of only checking ParseUser as null, I check username too:

```
ParseUser currentUser=ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
if(currentUser==null)
        {
//user doesn't exist
        }
else
{
if(currentUser.getUserName()==null)
{
//user oesn't exist
}
}
```

Comment: so you can say: if(crntUser != null && crntUser.getUsername() != null){ //user exist } else {// user doesn't exist}

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().logOut();
```

Comment: That is the same thing

Comment: Thanks Kaypey, but it didn't work either. Additionally, logOut() is a static method, it doesn't make any difference to call it directly on an instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Actually it was a bug in parse sdk and the problem was solved without changing any of my code, just by installing the latest parse android sdk(1.8.1 at the time of writing).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue it was because i has automatic user enabled which causes a new anonymous user to be created, it is also explained here
https://www.parse.com/questions/issues-with-parseuserlogout-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Try to logout the current user object, not the class.

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().logout();
```

and make sure to delete

```
ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
```

Edit:
When you logout, the User instance will still available, but with null fields. Parse changes all the user's fields into nulls.

So, if you want to check whether the user is logged in or out, just do the following

```
if(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername() == null)
{ // user is out 
} else { 
// user is in }
```