# Android: ParseUser.getCurrentUser() returning empty object even after Logout

Tags: java, android, authentication, parse-platform

In my Android code i am checking the condition on parse current user. if user is logged in them some action is performing and if not other action is performing. but when i am checking the condition even after user is logged out the ParseUser.getCurrentUser() is returning object, when i am trying to access data via parseCurrentUserObject the app is crashing, getting either NullpointerException or IllegalStateException.

i also gone through the link [Parse for Android : ParseUser.logOut() doesn't log user out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254545/parse-for-android-parseuser-logout-doesnt-log-user-out) 
but din't workout for me.

code is -

`

```
ParseUser.logOut();
    if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null) {
          Log.d("userType: ", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("userType")
                            .toString());
          tabSettingForPrivateUser(rootView);
    } else {
          tabSettingForPublicUser(rootView);
    }
```

`

app is crashing at log message where i am trying to access data from object:

```
Log.d("userType: ", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("userType").toString());
```

LogCat error message at this line -

```
08-15 17:58:05.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1220): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How to deal with this problem ?

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Answer (score 0):

The documentation very clearly says:

`public static void logOut()`

> Logs out the currently logged in user
>   session. This will remove the session from disk, log out of linked
>   services, and future calls to ParseUser.getCurrentUser() will return
>   null.

If the method call to `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` does not behave as expected, then this is a bug in the API.

Have you tried using the debugger and setting a breakpoint to see what variables are null when your app crashes?  Are you sure that the `String` you are getting isn't null?

Also, you are using a key to access the value in the `ParseObject`. It is definitely a good idea to keep the keys centralized in an `interface`. Makes debugging a lot easier and the code more maintainable. Writing the raw string value for the key is definitely a recipe for disaster.

Comment: even after Logout ParseUser.logOut(); getting current user not null

Comment: @Meg Sure. I got that point. However, when your app crashes, due to an `NPE`, what variable is `null`? Use a debugger, set a breakpoint and reply back :)

Comment: Actually ParseUser.getCurrentUser() method is returning the empty object, means  ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null (object is not null) but when i am trying to access currentUser.getObjectId() then it is giving NPE thats what the debugger says and app crashes.